# Minimality in the case of partial derivatives and Sobolev spaces?

Tags: terminology, sobolev-spaces, partial-derivative

I am trying to understand this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508139/find-minimal-alpha-3-such-that-u-in-h3-omega-and-ux-y-z-x-alpha1-x) that considers Sobolev spaces apparently and hence partial derivatives. What is the definition of minimality there? Is the minimality defined by cardinality or by the less-or-equal operation i.e. *"x is the minimal element if it is less or equal to any other element"* where the less-or-equal can also mean $\subseteq$? So simply

> **What does the minimality usually mean in the case of the partial derivatives and Sobolev spaces?**

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the question you linked to, $\alpha$ is a real number and $\alpha_3$ being minimal is to be interpreted in the usual sense for real numbers.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not seem to answer the question. When you have earned some reputation, you will be able to post comments.

Comment: @MårtenW: what do you mean this doesn't answer the question? Please follow the OP's link to the other question where the context is given. This perfectly answer the question "What is the definition of minimality there?"

Comment: I did follow the link, but I interpreted the question as actually being _two_ related questions, namely (1) what definition of "minimal" was used, and (2) what minimality would mean in terms of the partial derivatives. Since you did not address (2), I thought it was not a full answer, but I may have been wrong.

Comment: @MårtenW Sobolev spaces infer partial derivatives, more [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SobolevSpace.html), so one thing related to Sobolev spaces where partial derivatives used in the definition. I want to make sure I understand things 100% correctly.